# YUI: displaying a dialog when clicking a label in treeview

Tags: menu, dialog, treeview, listener, yui

I am using  yui tree to populate the menu
and once u click on any menu item i need to open a yui dialog.My code is like this

```
    tree = new YAHOO.widget.TreeView("treeDiv1");

var root = tree.getRoot();

var myobj = {
    label : "Account Search",
    myNodeId : "myid1",
    labelStyle : "mymenu"   

};
var tmpNode = new YAHOO.widget.MenuNode(myobj, root, false);
var myobj = {
    label : "Activate Account",
    myNodeId : "myid1",
    labelStyle : "mymenu"   
};
var tmpNodel2 = new YAHOO.widget.MenuNode(myobj, root, false);

var myobj = {
    label : "Code of the Day",
    myNodeId : "myid1",
    labelStyle : "mymenu"   
};
var tmpNodel3 = new YAHOO.widget.MenuNode(myobj, root, false);
     tree.render();
```

for this labels i want to add listeners , when i click i should open a yui dialog by using yaho.widget.dialog().for this i will give parameter divid which is in another gsp(grails).adding the listener to myNodeId is not working . can anyone suggest how to add listeners to these labels in the menu.. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add listeners to individual labels but listen to the labelClick event as shown here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/#events

and then you branch on the value read for myNodeId or whatever you want to decide upon from the node.

Comment: thank you i used tree.subscribe('clickEvent', function(oArgs) {
  
  oArgs.node.label
  
  

 }); to get the event